# How to set the parent of jDialog in netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, setparent

I'm pretty confused about this, since I haven't been working with jdialogs so far...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change jFrame to jDialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671322/change-jframe-to-jdialog) - your question was already answered there. If you need clarification, please edit your original question or post a comment to the answer asking the person for additional help.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Netbeans, just a basic Java program.

Answer (score 2):

When you call the constructor for JDialog, you need to pass in the JFrame that owns it. This [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Frame,%20boolean%29) is useful, because it allows you to specify it as a modal dialog. Sometimes this can be difficult if the code that launches the dialog is related to a panel, in this case you need to get a reference to the frame that launches the dialog in some way.